# PyTorch: Custom batch sampler exhausts after first epoch

Tags: python, pytorch, pytorch-dataloader

I'm using a `DataLoader` with a custom `batch_sampler` to ensure each batch is class balanced. How do I prevent the iterator from exhausting itself on the first epoch?

```
import torch

class CustomDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = torch.rand(10, 10)
        self.y = torch.Tensor([0] * 5 + [1] * 5)
        
    def __len__(self):
        len(self.y)
        
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]

def custom_batch_sampler():
    batch_idx = [[0, 5], [1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9]]
    return iter(batch_idx)

def train(loader):
    for epoch in range(10):
        for batch, (x, y) in enumerate(loader):
            print('epoch:', epoch, 'batch:', batch) # stops after first epoch

if __name__=='__main__':
    my_dataset = CustomDataset()
    my_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
        dataset=my_dataset,
        batch_sampler=custom_batch_sampler()
    )
    train(my_loader)
```

Training stops after the first epoch and `next(iter(loader))` gives a `StopIteration` error.

```
epoch: 0 batch: 0
epoch: 0 batch: 1
epoch: 0 batch: 2
epoch: 0 batch: 3
epoch: 0 batch: 4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom batch sampler needs to be a `Sampler` or some iterable. In each epoch a new iterator is generated from this iterable. This means you don't actually need to manually make an iterator (which will run out and raise `StopIteration` after the first epoch), but you can just provide your list, so it should work if you remove the `iter()`:

```
def custom_batch_sampler():
    batch_idx = [[0, 5], [1, 6], [2, 7], [3, 8], [4, 9]]
    return batch_idx
```